# FH (familial hypercholesterolemia)and LDL Receptors

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology

I'm trying to understand how FH affects LDL receptors. Does FH affect the function of LDL receptors (mutates them) or the number of LDL receptors at the plasma membrane at any given point? Or both?